# How to give a status check in / check out based on time in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, time

I have this problem with SQL, described in the image below. Is there a way to solve the problem ?

[image: Image and Description]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ROW_NUMBER concept :

```
SELECT id , time , CASE WHEN MIN(RNo) = 1 THEN  'CheckIn' WHEN MAX(RNo) > 1     
THEN  'CheckOut' END
FROM 
(
  SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time) RNo 
  FROM @table
) A 
GROUP BY id , time
```

Comment: this syntax resuting error on "(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY time)"

Comment: @Diand,It's works fine in my end.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @table table (rowno int identity (1,1),id varchar(10),[time] time)
insert into @table
select '01','10:08:23'
union all
select '02','10:10:50'
union all
select '01','13:30:00'

;with cte as
(
select *,row_number()over(partition by id order by id)n from @table
)select id,time,case when n=1 then 'checkin' else 'checkout'end status from cte order by rowno
```

Comment: is this only applied to that 3 records? i need it to automatically applied to all records on the table. thanks!